# MySQL column value in LIKE query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a database.

Both contain a related id but in a different format:

```
table1.field = 123456-12-34
table2.id = 123456
```

What Im trying to do is  a `join` on `table1.id = table2.field`

so the query looks like:

```
select name from 
    table1 left join table2 on table1.field like table2-%
    where table2.flag='1' and DATEDIFF( now(), table1.timestamp ) > 2
```

I know this isn't correct, but how do i join two tables on fields where they are related but not the same?

Comment: Probably this will help you: [how to use a like with a join in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `concat()` to create the pattern string:

```
select name
from table1 left join
     table2
     on table1.field like concat(table2.id, '-%')
where table2.flag='1' and DATEDIFF( now(), table1.timestamp ) > 2
```