# Optimization dilema

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be the most optimized way? I'm building a kind of "social network". The users can upload photo albums, files or messages. Each one of this data is saved in a different table. The receivers are saved as their userId separated by a comma, as such: "1,2,3,4,". Now I want to grab everything that was sent for a user. I have 2 ways (that I know of) to do so.

1. Fetch each table separately(Not very efficient since I'll have to do a query for each row fetched to get the senders user from another table). And then process the data.
2. Join the 3 tables. But from what I understand I cant use LIKE in a JOIN.

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'receiver'?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about what you are asking but storing `1,2,3,4,etc...` is a terrible idea.

Comment: @BrianKendig the one the file/msg/album is sent

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE in a JOIN (see [how to use a like with a join in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql)), but if I understand you properly, you shouldn't represent your receivers as a comma-separated string list. Instead, use another table with a separate record for every receiver-item relationship, so that you can query on it without needing to use LIKE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` in a `join`.  The expression that you are looking for is something like:

```
on find_in_set(a.value, b.list) > 0
```

However, this is not recommended, because MySQL cannot optimize the performance of the query using indexes.  In other words, the items that you have in a list should be separate rows in a junction/association table.

If you need to do joins like this, then you should normalize your data structure.  That means, don't store lists in comma-delimited fields.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a LOT bigger database?

Comment: It is the right way to store this type of data, and databases are designed to handle these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a graph database.

You can pick something ready-made for that purpose or try to map your graph to SQL database.

For example like this:

- users table
- sender-receiver table (both foreign keys to user)
- item extension table (extends sender-receiver)

something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (varchar user_id, varchar email, etc...);
CREATE TABLE link (varchar sender, varchar recepient)
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (sender) REFERENCES user (user_id)
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (recepient) REFERENCES user (user_id);
CREATE TABLE aldbum (varchar sender, varchar recepient, album stuff)
   CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (sender, receipient) REFERENCES link (sender, recepient);
-- repeat extension tables for files, messages
```