# Join MySQL tables based on Partial match of Strings

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables that I want to join
`Domain` and `Links` with 1k rows and with 700k rows respectively

```
create table Domain (url varchar(255), tag varchar(255));
create table Links (ShortURL varchar(255), LongURL varchar(255));
```

The output should be joined on partial match of ALL strings `Domain.url` found in `Links.LongURL` and the result should return 700k rows from the `Links` table and where no match found should be `null`

Tried the following from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930809/mysql-join-query-using-like) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql)

```
SELECT ShortURL,LongURL,tag
FROM Links fulljoin Domain 
ON Links.LongURL LIKE concat('%', Domain.url, '%');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be a time consuming operation.  Your query is on the right track, but the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT ShortURL, l.LongURL, tag
FROM Links l LEFT JOIN
     Domain d
     ON l.LongURL LIKE concat('%', d.url, '%');
```

That said, with your two tables, this query is going to take a while.  It needs to do about 700,000,000 comparisons using `like`.  There is no easy way to speed up the query.

Comment: Given the "no match found should return null" you probably want a left join.

Answer (score 1):

In order to return all `Links` regardless of whether there is a matching `Domain`, you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

To make sure each `Links` row is returned only once, you should `GROUP BY` the `Links` columns and just return one `Domain` (using an aggregate function like `MIN()` or `MAX()`) in case there are multiple `Domain` matches for a given `Links` row.

Something like this:

```
select Links.ShortURL, Links.LongURL, min(Domain.tag)
from Links 
  left outer join Domain on Links.LongURL like concat('%', Domain.url, '%')
group by Links.ShortURL, Links.LongURL
```

Your existing `LIKE` statement will be very slow, and cannot benefit from an index on `Links.LongURL`. How are you storing the URLs and domains? If they have a consistent prefix, for example all `Links.LongURL` and `Domain.url` values start with `https://`, then you could add an index on `Links.LongURL`, get rid of the leading wildcard, and make the query much faster, like this:

```
select Links.ShortURL, Links.LongURL, min(Domain.tag)
from Links 
  left outer join Domain on Links.LongURL like concat(Domain.url, '%')
group by Links.ShortURL, Links.LongURL
```

Answer (score 1):

If the DOMAIN Name start every time at the begin of the string you can speed up like this. than can MySQL use a INDEX:

```
SELECT ShortURL,LongURL,tag
FROM Links fulljoin Domain 
ON
  Links.LongURL LIKE concat(Domain.url, '%')
OR
  Links.LongURL LIKE concat('www.',Domain.url, '%');
```