# MySQL LIKE Using % Symbol form join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 simple table:

**Table a:**

```
+====+======+
| ID | Name |
+====+======+
| 1  | Alex |
| 2  | Steve|
+===========+
```

**Table b:**

```
+======+======+
| ID_B |Number|
+======+======+
| 1-20 | 20   |
| 1-21 | 40   |
+=============+
```

**I tied to use this syntax:**

```
SELECT `Name`,sum(`Number`) From `a` Join `b` ON `a`.`ID` LIKE `b`.`ID_B`+'%'
```

I don't know all about Mysql, am a newbie.
I want to join table **a** to table **b**, and in table **b** Number's is automatically count all WHERE ID table **a** is Same like **b** .ID_B %

Finally my answer is **"Alex have 60 Number"**.

Comment: What is `ID_B`, and why isn't it a foreign key? Or I guess rather, you need a foreign key.

Comment: @Rogue, that just example, i want to marge all table WHERE same ID

Comment: Finally Answer is **Alex Have 60 Number**

Comment: So Steve is also 60 because it is in 1 upto 20? Or does 1-20.meen only 1 and 20 match?

Comment: The information in `ID_B` should be separate columns basically. E.g. `1-21` would become columns of `1` and `21`, and you'd put what is called a "Foreign Key Constraint" between `a#ID` and `b#ID` (assuming the `1` is in a new column named `ID`, I'm not sure of the purpoes of the second number). Lastly you'd do a SUM function in the select (on `b#Number`) and a GROUP BY for the id.

Comment: That table can't to use that?, i have searching at google, and i find solution but it not work for me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql

Comment: they are work, but why i can't? @Rogue

Comment: Because it's silly to do a `LIKE` on a join vs `a.id = b.id`, both speed and code-wise. The `ON` is merely a conditional clause which specifies what makes a row in table `a`, and a row in table `b` "match".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- swap the positions of `a.id` and `bid_b` in the `like` operator (the longer of the two values should be on the left so its remaining part matches the wildcard on the right)
- convert the `a.id` to string and concatenate it to `%`, which you can do with `concat`. Even though you have a reference, the `+` operator does not concatenate strings in MySql
- also better add a `group by`

It would look like this:

```
select   name, sum(number) 
from     a 
join     b 
      on b.b_id like concat(a.id, '%') 
group by name
```

Depending on your case, you might want to add the hyphen before the `%`:

```
      on b.b_id like concat(a.id, '-%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a4f49/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES
(1, 'Alex'),
(2, 'Steeve');

CREATE TABLE b (
  ID_B VARCHAR(25),
  Number INT
);

INSERT INTO b VALUES
('1-20', 20),
('1-21', 40);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a.NAME, t.* FROM a LEFT JOIN (SELECT LEFT(ID_B, INSTR(ID_B, '-') - 1) AS ID, SUM(Number) 
FROM b
GROUP BY LEFT(ID_B, INSTR(ID_B, '-') + 1)) AS t
ON (a.ID = t.ID)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a4f49/6/0)**:

```
|   NAME |     ID | SUM(Number) |
|--------|--------|-------------|
|   Alex |      1 |          60 |
| Steeve | (null) |      (null) |
```