# SQL Interpolated Strings

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, interpolation

Does T-SQL support Interpolated String?

Let's put up this example:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + @somevariable + ' FROM SOME_TABLE'
```

I want to be able to do something like that:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT {@somevariable} FROM SOME_TABLE'
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: in some cases `CONCAT()` function can be used. [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Giving the credits to @j.f.sebastian for pointing out these solutions. Sadly xp_sprintf is limited to 254 characters, so that wouldn't be ideal when using long queries. FORMATMESSAGE instead is limited to 2047 characters, so that's good enough in order to run long queries.

I'll summarize everything in one post for the solutions in order to keep things organized.

## Answer 1:

Using [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql) it's important to know, that using interpolated string as first the parameter, Its supported only SQL versions 2012 and above, so I'll post 2 answers with FORMATMESSAGE:

SQL Version >= 2012:

```
SET @query = FORMATMESSAGE('SELECT %s FROM SOME_TABLE', @somevariable);
```

SQL Version < 2012:

```
EXEC sp_addmessage 50001, 16, 'SELECT %s FROM SOME_TABLE', NULL, NULL, 'replace'
SET @query = FORMATMESSAGE(50001, @somevariable)
```

## Answer 2:

Using [xp_sprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-sprintf-transact-sql) stored procedure is important to note that It's limited to 254 characters, so it won't be a good idea for long queries.

```
DECLARE  @query AS VARCHAR(100)
        ,@somevariable as VARCHAR(10) = '[id]'
EXEC xp_sprintf @query OUTPUT, 'SELECT %s FROM SOME_TABLE', @somevariable
```

Comment: thanks for credit. Didn't have time to come back and edit my answer yesterday - you should mark this as accepted answer as it gives the detail!

Comment: The `sp_addmessage` approach has the important drawback that it is not safe when executed concurrently from multiple sessions. This can lead to some pretty confusing messages. The technique is still useful, but care should be taken that it is not used whenever you need interpolation, as that would increase the chances of a clash considerably. Also, from SQL Server 2012 onwards, there is `CONCAT` to simplify cobbling together strings without having to add `CONVERT`s everywhere.

Comment: Thank you sebastian! That's a good idea, done.
@JeroenMostert, an example would be amazing please. Thanks

Comment: It appears `FORMATMESSAGE(string, ...`) only works from `SQL Server 2016 (13.x)`.

Answer (score 8):

For readability when your strings are long I like doing this:

```
SET @query = replace( replace( replace( 
               'SELECT {@variable1} FROM {@variable2} WHERE {@variable3}'
               , '{@variable1}', @variable1 )
               , '{@variable2}', @variable2 )
               , '{@variable3}', @variable3 )
```

It has the advantage of readability of the SQL string plus you can use the same variable multiple times. Clearly it's not proper interpolation but I like it better than the `FORMATMESSAGE()` option since

- It doesn't have a length limitation. Who writes queries shorter than 2047 characters anyway?! ;)
- It supports named placeholders instead of just ordered ones
- Supported in any version of SQL Server
- You can use the same placeholder multiple times

Comment: beautiful format, that's what I need, thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's not a common way of doing things in T-SQL but it is possible with [xp_sprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-sprintf-transact-sql)

```
    DECLARE  @query AS VARCHAR(100)
            ,@somevariable as VARCHAR(10) = '[id]'
    EXEC xp_sprintf @query OUTPUT, 'SELECT %s FROM SOME_TABLE', @somevariable

    PRINT @query
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But unfortunately i found limitation with this answer. It's worth to mention that xp_sprintf is limited to 254 characters :( So long queries won't work with that.

Comment: Sorry - thats annoying.  I just found another function that could help - FORMATMESSAGE - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql

Comment: According to the FORMATMESSAGE documentation the limit is 2047 characters - hope that is enough for your requirements!

Comment: FORMATMESSAGE looks promising, but it supports only SQL versions >= 2016. I'm using the 2008 community edition, so it can only support the build in messages, which means, having my own string as first parameter won't work. Thanks for taking the time posting these links tho! I can confirm since i have also SQL 2017 server and 2008 installed.

Comment: Found a workaround for that, even tho It's a bit ugly. We need to add custom message manually and then we can use the custom message number:
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum=50001, @severity=16, @msgtext=@query, @replace='replace'

Do you mind posting it as another answer so i can mark as accepted? Thanks a ton for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I like doing this for my dynamic SQL, so I [wrote a function for SQL Server 2017+](https://github.com/StevenHibble/T-SQL-Tools/blob/master/StringInterpolation.sql) (uses STRING_AGG and JSON_VALUE). It could be rewritten to make it compatible with older versions.

Here's the text in case that link dies:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [Tools].[StringInterpolation] 
 (@Template VARCHAR(MAX)
, @JSON_Row NVARCHAR(MAX))
/*
This function replaces a string template with actual values from a JSON-formatted row
The table returns a single column: FormattedString

** Requires SQL Server 2017+ for STRING_AGG (could be rewritten using XML PATH)
** Requires SQL Server 2016+ for JSON_VALUE (maybe you could use XML)

EXAMPLE: 
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Name] = 'Steven', Adjective = 'internet person',        Verb = 'writes helpful(?) SQL functions') [d]
CROSS APPLY Tools.StringInterpolation ('{Name} is a {Adjective} who {Verb}.', (SELECT [d].* FOR JSON PATH))

Name   | Adjective              | Verb                            | FormattedString
-------+------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
Steven | internet person        | writes helpful(?) SQL functions | Steven is a internet person who writes helpful(?) SQL functions.
*/ 
RETURNS TABLE
  RETURN
  WITH [CTE_10]
       AS (SELECT [Number]
           FROM(VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1) ) [v]([Number])),
       -------------------
       /* 100 rows (all 1s) */
       [CTE_100]
       AS (SELECT [Number] = 1
           FROM [CTE_10] [a]
                CROSS JOIN [CTE_10] [b]),
       -------------------
       /* 1,000,000 rows max (all 1s) */
       [CTE_1000000]
       AS (SELECT [Number] = 1
           FROM [CTE_100] [a]
                CROSS JOIN [CTE_100] [b]
                CROSS JOIN [CTE_100] [c]),
       -------------------
       /* Numbers "Table" CTE: 1) TOP has variable parameter = DATALENGTH(@Template), 2) Use ROW_NUMBER */
       [CTE_Numbers]
       AS (SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@Template), 0)) 
                  [Number] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )
           FROM [CTE_1000000]),
       -------------------

       /* This is tricky. Get each start of each variable or non-variable
          Variables look like {...}
          Non-variables look like }...{ (i.e. the bits between the variables) */
       [CTE_Start]
       AS (SELECT [Type] = 'Text'
                , [Start] = 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT [Type] = IIF([Char] = '{', 'Variable', 'Text')
                , [Start] = [Number] + 1 -- start *after* the { or }
           FROM [CTE_Numbers]
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Char] = SUBSTRING(@Template, [Number], 1)) [c]
           WHERE [Char] IN ( '{', '}' ) ),
       -------------------

       /* Pair each "start" with the next to find indicies of each substring */
       [CTE_StringIndicies]
       AS (SELECT [Type]
                , [Start]
                , [End] = ISNULL(LEAD([Start]) OVER(
                                 ORDER BY [Start]) - 1, DATALENGTH(@Template) + 1)
           FROM [CTE_Start]),
       -------------------

       /* Get each substring */
       [CTE_Variables]
       AS (SELECT [Start]
                , [Type]
                , [SubString] = SUBSTRING(@Template, [Start], [End] - [Start])
           FROM [CTE_StringIndicies]),
       -------------------

       /* If it's a variable, replace it with the actual value from @JSON_Row
          Otherwise, just return the original substring */
       [CTE_Replacements]
       AS (SELECT [Start]
                , [Substring] = IIF([Type] = 'Variable', JSON_VALUE(@JSON_Row, '$[0].' + [Substring]), [Substring])
           FROM [CTE_Variables])
       -------------------

       /* Glue it all back together */
       SELECT [FormattedString] = STRING_AGG([Substring], '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Start])
       FROM [CTE_Replacements];
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrote 2 handy **Json** based interpolation functions. One makes use of a dictionary style Json (key, value pairs), the other a Json object containing a property for each substitution.

**1) Data as Json object**

For example, given the template: `'Hey, {name} is {age}'`, run:

```
SELECT [res4] = [ccgen].[fn_string_interpolation_object]('Hi, {name} is {age}' ,'{"name":"Alice", "age":24}')
```

... which returns `Hey, Alice is 24`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [CcGen].[fn_string_interpolation_object](
   @template NVARCHAR(4000), @data_json NVARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000) AS

   /*
   =============================================
   C# or Java like string interpolation brought to TSQL.

   example - copy to run proc
   -----------------------
   --property names must match those in template. Same as a dynamic object in C#

   SELECT [res4] = [ccgen].[fn_string_interpolation_object]('Hi, {name} is {age}' ,'{"name":"Alice", "age":24}')

   -- returns
   Hi, Alic is 24
   =============================================
   */

BEGIN
   SELECT @template = REPLACE(@template ,'{' + [key] + '}' ,[value]) FROM OPENJSON(@data_json);
   RETURN @template;
END;
```

**2) Data as Json dictionary**
For example, given the template: `'Hey, {name} is {age}'`, run:

```
SELECT [res2] = [ccgen].[fn_string_interpolation]('Hey, {name} is {age}','{"items":[{"key":"name", "value":"Alice"},{"key":"age", "value":"24"}]}')
```

... which returns `Hey, Alice is 24`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [CcGen].[fn_string_interpolation](
   @template NVARCHAR(4000), 
   @key_value_json NVARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000) AS

   /*
   =============================================
   C# or Java like string interpolation brought to TSQL.
   
   example - copy to run proc
   -----------------------

   DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2048) = N'{
    "items": [
        {
            "key": "A",
            "value": "a1"
        },
        {
            "key": "B",
            "value": "b2"
        },
        {
            "key": "C",
            "value": "c3"
        }
    ]
}';

   DECLARE @template NVARCHAR(4000) = 'message:= A:{A}, B:{B}, C:{C}'
   select res = ccgen.fn_string_interpolation(@template, @json)

   -- returns
   formatted 3 = A:a1, B:b2, C:c3
   =============================================
   */

BEGIN
   SELECT @template = REPLACE(@template ,'{' + [key] + '}' ,[value]) FROM OPENJSON(@key_value_json ,'$.items') WITH ( [key] VARCHAR(200) '$.key', [value] VARCHAR(4000) '$.value' );
   RETURN @template;
END;
```

Tip: The Json takes a little more typing. Modify the code and shorten property names to "k" (key) ,"v" (value) and "d" (items) to make it tiny. Then calling is neater:

```
SELECT [res2] = [ccgen].[fn_string_interpolation]('Hey, {name} is {age}','{"d":[{"k":"name", "v":"Alice"},{"k":"age", "v":"24"}]}')
```

Notes:

Naturally this will only work on MSSQL versions that support Json. Also there is no support for escaping. For example it's not possible to have {a} as both a literal and a substitution param. This could be added using escaping but can't warrant the effort since I have no use for the feature.

Answer (score 1):

To add another option, my preference is for a pseudo-interpolated string approach. T-SQL doesn't actually support string interpolation, but I find it easier to keep track of things this way. It's basically a fancy `REPLACE()`, without needing some varying number of nested `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(...)` calls.

```
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Some {item} with {count} {collection}.';

SELECT @message = REPLACE(@message, SearchText, ReplaceText)
FROM ( VALUES
  ('{item}', 'text string'),
  ('{count}', '3'),
  ('{collection}', 'variables')
) _ (SearchText, ReplaceText);
```

You can replace the placeholders with string literals, other variables, etc., and it's really easy to handle many replacements without keeping track of all the nesting. You can use whatever you want for the placeholder, but I just borrowed the style from other languages because it stands out well from the rest of the text.