# How to join tables on prefix equality?

Tags: r, join, tidyverse, match, left-join

I have a table with prefixes (here in csv format):

```
PREFIX,LABEL
A,Infectious diseases
B,Infectious diseases
C,Tumor
D1,Tumor
D2,Tumor
D31,Tumor
D32,Tumor
D33,Blood disorder
D4,Blood disorder
D5,Blood disorder
```

And I want to join it with this one:

```
AGE,DEATH_CODE
67,A02
85,D318
75,C007+X
62,D338
```

To get obviously:

```
AGE,LABEL
67,Infectious diseases
85,Tumor
75,Tumor
62,Blood disorder
```

I know how to do that with SQL and `LIKE` but not with tidyverse `left_join` or base R.

---

### Dput of data

#### Table 1: CIM_CODES

```
structure(list(PREFIX = c("A", "B", "C", "D1", "D2", "D31", "D32", 
"D33", "D4", "D5"), LABEL = c("Infectious diseases", "Infectious diseases", 
"Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Tumor", "Blood disorder", 
"Blood disorder", "Blood disorder")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(PREFIX = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), LABEL = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000002527d306190>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Table 2: DEATH_CAUSES

```
structure(list(AGE = c(67, 85, 75, 62), DEATH_CODE = c("A02", 
"D318", "C007+X", "D338")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(AGE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), DEATH_CODE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000025273898c60>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you share your data with dput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a partial string match that has the lowest difference between the two columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DEATH_CAUSES |>
  mutate(LABEL = map_chr(DEATH_CODE, 
                         ~CIM_CODES$LABEL[
                           which.min(stringdist::stringdist(.x, CIM_CODES$PREFIX))
                           ]))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>     AGE DEATH_CODE LABEL              
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>              
#> 1    67 A02        Infectious diseases
#> 2    85 D318       Tumor              
#> 3    75 C007+X     Tumor              
#> 4    62 D338       Blood disorder
```

UPDATE
not using the `stringdist` package as requested.

```r
library(tidyverse)


get_match <- function(code, prefix, target){
  map(code, \(x){
    map(prefix, \(y){
      grepl(paste0("^", y), x)
      }) 
    }) |>
    map_chr(\(z) target[unlist(z) |> which()] )
}

DEATH_CAUSES |>
  mutate(LABEL = get_match(DEATH_CAUSES$DEATH_CODE, 
                           CIM_CODES$PREFIX, 
                           CIM_CODES$LABEL))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>     AGE DEATH_CODE LABEL              
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>              
#> 1    67 A02        Infectious diseases
#> 2    85 D318       Tumor              
#> 3    75 C007+X     Tumor              
#> 4    62 D338       Blood disorder
```

EDIT
how to do this with a join:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(DEATH_CAUSES, 
                CIM_CODES, 
                by = c("DEATH_CODE" = "PREFIX"), 
                str_detect)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>     AGE DEATH_CODE PREFIX LABEL              
#>   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>              
#> 1    67 A02        A      Infectious diseases
#> 2    85 D318       D31    Tumor              
#> 3    75 C007+X     C      Tumor              
#> 4    62 D338       D33    Blood disorder
```

Comment: Very interesting! But I do not have the `stringdist` pakcage installed on my RStudio server...

Comment: Okay, let me see if I can do something in base. Do you have `tidyverse`?

Comment: Okay I updated to remove the `stringdist` package.

Comment: Very impressive... I am surprised that this use case does not have its tidyverse verb!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. What do you mean by tidyverse verb? `map` and `mutate` are both from the `tidyverse`

Comment: This is a simple variation of `left_join`as we can see in SQL just using LIKE instead of equal. We could `left_join` with `like` option

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated to show how to do this with a join. You need to use another package called `fuzzyjoin`.

Comment: I have a performance issue with my real use case...

Answer (score -1):

My code below, I used mysql:

```
select a.age, p.label 
from prefix p
left join age a on a.death_code like CONCAT("%",p.prefix,"%");
```

You can refer here: [how to use a like with a join in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386166/how-to-use-a-like-with-a-join-in-sql)

Comment: I know how to do that in SQL but  this is an `R` question as you can see in the [tags]. Moreover your answer does not really work because you have to write `concat(p.prefix, "%")` because this is a prefix.